# stop other users to browse to some pages of my website

Tags: php

In my website i have used ajax at many places... But the problem is that the file, lets say some_ajax_file.php, is visible in the source code... I want that other users dont just type this in the url and go to this page... If they do so, they will then be redirected to another page...

I tried following code on that ajax page:

```
function curPageName() {
     return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

$cur_page=curPageName();
```

and checked it

```
if($cur_page=="some_ajax_file.php")
//then redirect...
```

it is working if the type some_ajax_file.php in the url...but the problem is that the the ajax function where i used this some_ajax_file.php is not working....plz help me ....i m stuck....

Comment: how is it not working? you're not telling us what the problem is

Comment: use Session in that page... check whether the Session Available or Not... If available then allo... if NOT just redirect them...

Comment: @janus...I have used a redirection on the some_ajax_file.php page...but when i click the link on the home page which is using this some_ajax_file.php...it removes that link from the home page and whole page gets messed up...bcoz it is putting that redirect page into my homepage...

Comment: is there any way to hide this some_ajax_file.php in the source code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to search for `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')
{
   // I'm AJAX!
}
else
{
     header();
     die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Session at the time of Login**

```
<?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['Username']= Userid;
?>
```

and check the Session Available on that Page...

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    //Redirect them to common page....
}
```

if the session availed then Show the page

Otherwise redirect them to login page....

Comment: Hey Pandian....its not about login...its about ajax....i have used this  feature already, the one you showed me....lets say...you have a like/unlike button on your homepage...and there is an ajax function associated with this like/unlike button...using l-ul.php....now suppose if user just type this in the url http://homepage.com/l-ul.php....then what